# Terraform append tags

Tags: tags, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I create VPC and subnets which I add tags.

Later, I create EKS cluster which appends its own tags and if I `apply` again, the tags are overwritten.

I need any method to read the current tags and then merge with my custom tags. The problem is if the VPC resources are being created for the first time I can't query if some tags exists.

Here is my subnets definition

```
resource "aws_subnet" "k8s" {
  count = "${var.create_vpc && length(var.k8s_subnets) > 0 ? length(var.k8s_subnets) : 0}"

  vpc_id            = "${local.vpc_id}"
  cidr_block        = "${var.k8s_subnets[count.index]}"
  availability_zone = "${element(var.azs, count.index)}"

  tags = "${merge(map("Name", format("subnet-%s-${var.k8s_subnet_suffix}-%s", var.name, element(var.azs, count.index))), var.tags, var.k8s_subnet_tags)}"
}
```

This is the tag EKS adds:

```
kubernetes.io/cluster/eks-cluster : shared
```

I'm stuck with this kind of... which comes first, the chicken or the egg?  Any idea or suggestion?

-- Edited

something like self.tags could be the solution but unfortunately is not possible:

> self.ATTRIBUTE syntax is only allowed and valid within provisioners.

and it shows an error:

```
Error: resource 'aws_subnet.k8s' config: cannot contain self-reference self.tags
```

Comment: If the tag that gets added by EKS Is deterministic, I'd simply include it within Terraform.

Comment: I'm creating some kind of infrastructure bootstrap for new projects. I have completely separated modules (in fact each one is in a different git repository) so I create all the necessary network infrastructure and maybe a month later I create the EKS cluster so I don't know previously even the name of the cluster. That's the reason it could be great the possibility to append tags :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do:

1. I define the common tags in env.sh which wraps terraform
2. When creating another component, I do this: tags                        = "${merge(var.default_tags, map("Name", format("%s-Jenkins-ELB", var.env)))}"
3. You could write the VPC tags to SSM parameter store and retrieve them later to be use by the EKS cluster.

Comment: That is not appending tags but it's a point to investigate. I'm thinking to add the subnets and routes creation inside the k8s module, that's makes sense but I have the same problem with the VPC's tags that I can't create the VPC within k8s module

Comment: The goal is  for SSM to be your tag list of record, so you can read it, append, update, and your resources will automatically get updated if you pass the list of tags from SSM.